# How do I create a McKelvey resource classification diagram using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do I create a McKelvey resource classification diagram as shown below using TikZ?
[image: McKelvey resource classification diagram]

Comment: Can you post some code showing your attempt so far? What features are you having problems with?

Comment: Sorry for my first attempt to ask a question here. I have some experience with creating simple graphs with tikz for my thesis. My problem creating this diagram is that I could not find code examples of similar diagrams. In particular for creating the multiple annotations with arrows and creating the boxes. I will try to create a minimal myself. Thank you for your quick response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an initial attempt hopefully sampling the main steps.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[generaloptions/.style 2 args={
draw,thick,inner sep=0,outer sep=0,minimum height=#1,minimum width=#2
}]
\node[generaloptions={2.5cm}{3cm},fill=blue!50!black] (big) at (0,0) {};
\node[generaloptions={1cm}{1.5cm},anchor=south west,fill=yellow] (y1) at (big.north west) {};
\node[generaloptions={1cm}{1.5cm},anchor=south east,fill=yellow] (y2) at (big.north east) {};
\node[generaloptions={0.75cm}{1.5cm},anchor=south west,fill=red] (r1) at (y1.north west) {};
\node[generaloptions={0.75cm}{1.5cm},anchor=south east,fill=red] (r2) at (y2.north east) {};
\node[scale=0.8,rotate=30] (rotlab) at (y1.north east) {RESOURCE};

\node[rotate=90,scale=0.3] at ([xshift=-1mm]r1.west) {\textit{ECONOMIC}};

\coordinate (lu) at ([xshift=-1cm]r1.north west);
\coordinate (ll) at ([xshift=-1cm]big.south west);
\coordinate (lm1) at ([xshift=-0.5cm]y1.south west);
\draw[shorten >=1mm] (lu) -- (r1.north west);
\draw[shorten >=1mm] (ll) -- (big.south west);
\draw[shorten >=1mm] (lm1) -- (y1.south west);

\draw[latex-latex,shorten <=0.5mm,shorten >=0.5mm] ([xshift=1mm]ll) -- 
        ([xshift=1mm]lu) node[sloped,fill=white,pos=0.5,scale=0.5] {\textit{RESOURCE BASE}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After some trial and error I managed to get this result:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[generaloptions/.style 2 args={
draw,thick,inner sep=0,outer sep=0,minimum height=#1,minimum width=#2
}]
\node[generaloptions={5cm}{9cm},fill=blue!50!black] (big) at (0,0) {};
\node[generaloptions={2.5cm}{4.5cm},anchor=south west,fill=yellow] (y1) at (big.north west) {};
\node[generaloptions={2.5cm}{4.5cm},anchor=south east,fill=yellow] (y2) at (big.north east) {};
\node[generaloptions={1.75cm}{4.5cm},anchor=south west,fill=orange] (r1) at (y1.north west) {};
\node[generaloptions={1.75cm}{4.5cm},anchor=south east,fill=orange] (r2) at (y2.north east) {};
\node[generaloptions={1.75cm}{4.5cm},anchor=south west,fill=red] (s1) at (r1.north west) {};
\node[generaloptions={1.75cm}{4.5cm},anchor=south east,fill=orange] (s2) at (r2.north east) {};
\node[scale=0.8,rotate=45] (rotlab) at (r1.north east) {\textbf{RESOURCE}};

\node[rotate=90,scale=0.4] at ([xshift=-1mm]s1.west) {\textit{ECONOMIC}};
\node[rotate=90,scale=0.4] at ([xshift=-1mm]r1.west) {\textit{SUB ECONOMIC}};

\coordinate (lu) at ([xshift=-1.5cm]s1.north west);
\coordinate (ll) at ([xshift=-1.5cm]big.south west);
\coordinate (lm1) at ([xshift=-0.5cm]y1.south west);
\coordinate (lm2) at ([xshift=-1.5cm]y1.south west);
\coordinate (lm3) at ([xshift=-1.0cm]y1.north west);
\coordinate (lv) at ([yshift=0.5cm]s1.north west);
\coordinate (rv) at ([yshift=0.5cm]s2.north east);
\coordinate (mvl) at ([xshift=4.5cm]s1.north west);
\coordinate (mvu) at ([yshift=0.5cm, xshift=4.5cm]s1.north west);
\coordinate (mmvl) at ([yshift=1.0cm, ]s1.north west);
\coordinate (mmvr) at ([yshift=1.0cm, ]s2.north east);

\draw[shorten <=1mm] (s1.north west) -- (lv);
\draw[shorten <=1mm] (s2.north east) -- (rv);
\draw[shorten <=1mm] (mvl) -- (mvu);

\draw[shorten >=1mm] (lu) -- (s1.north west);
\draw[shorten >=1mm] (ll) -- (big.south west);
\draw[shorten >=1mm] (lm2) -- (y1.south west);
\draw[shorten >=1mm] (lm3) -- (y1.north west);

\draw[latex-latex,shorten <=0.5mm,shorten >=0.5mm] ([xshift=1mm]ll) -- 
    ([xshift=1mm]lu) node[sloped,fill=white,pos=0.5,scale=0.9] {\textit{RESOURCE BASE}};
\draw[latex-latex,shorten <=0.5mm,shorten >=0.5mm] ([xshift=5mm]ll) -- 
    ([xshift=5mm]lm2) node[sloped,fill=white,pos=0.5,scale=0.7] {\textit{INACCESSIBLE}}; 
\draw[latex-latex,shorten <=0.5mm,shorten >=0.5mm] ([xshift=5mm]lm2) -- 
    ([xshift=5mm]lu) node[sloped,fill=white,pos=0.5,scale=0.7] {\textit{ACCESSIBLE}};                 
\draw[latex-latex,shorten <=0.5mm,shorten >=0.5mm] ([xshift=10mm]lm2) -- 
    ([xshift=5mm]lm3) node[sloped,fill=white,pos=0.5,scale=0.6] {\textit{RESIDUAL}}; 
\draw[latex-latex,shorten <=0.5mm,shorten >=0.5mm] ([xshift=5mm]lm3) -- 
    ([xshift=10mm]lu) node[sloped,fill=white,pos=0.5,scale=0.6] {\textit{USEFUL}}; 
\draw[latex-latex,shorten <=0.5mm,shorten >=0.5mm] ([yshift=-2mm]lv) -- 
    ([yshift=-2mm]mvu) node[sloped,fill=white,pos=0.5,scale=0.6] {\textit{IDENTIFIED}};   
\draw[latex-latex,shorten <=0.5mm,shorten >=0.5mm] ([yshift=-2mm]mvu) -- 
    ([yshift=-2mm]rv) node[sloped,fill=white,pos=0.5,scale=0.6] {\textit{UNDISCOVERED}};                 

\draw[latex-latex, thick, shorten <=5mm] ([yshift=-2.5mm]mmvl) -- 
    ([yshift=2.5mm]mvu) node[sloped,fill=white,pos=1.0,scale=1] {\textit{\textbf{GEOLOGICAL ASSURANCE}}};   
\draw[latex-latex, thick, shorten <=25mm] ([xshift=11cm]ll) -- 
    ([xshift=10cm]lm1) node[sloped,fill=white,pos=1.0,scale=1] {\textit{\textbf{COST/DEPTH}}};   

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you've nailed it!

Comment: Thank you very much for the initial code. I just could not figure out myself how to tackle the problem.